# Do MassTransit or nServiceBus support MSMQ over HTTP transport?

Tags: msmq, nservicebus, masstransit

I understand it's available since MSMQ 3.0, is it available via any of the .NET ESBs?
Is this possible with other MQ transports (ActiveMQ, etc)?

Thanks,
E.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NServiceBus use msmq as its main transport but does not support the http option for Msmq.  Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? Perhaps the NServiceBus gateway component is what you need?

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/gateway/

Hope this helps!

Comment: We expect some services, while still integral parts of overall system, to reside in physically dispersed locations, possibly behind firewalls (to be close to the resources they will work with).

Comment: Ok, then the gateway is definitely an option for you. Have you read the docs?

Comment: What about Mass Transit? Do you have any info on it?

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit does not support MSMQ over HTTP in any way. RabbitMQ only requires a single port open for communication but it is not the HTTP (80 or 443) port.