# Does MassTransit support MSMQ over HTTP transport?

Tags: c#, .net, msmq, masstransit

HTTP transfer has been available since MSMQ 3.0, however I'm afraid MassTransit doesn't offer the feature to use HTTP protocol as transport protocol between queues.

There's a very similar question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602422/do-masstransit-or-nservicebus-support-msmq-over-http-transport), which has not been completely answered.

Does anyone know if it's possible for a client to subscribe to a bus and send/receive messages through HTTP? Here's the architecture I'm willing to implement:

I'll have 2 computers in the local network

- **Computer A** runs a server application and MassTransit.RuntimeServices
- **Computer B** runs a client application which sends messages to A

I want the communication between them to be done via http.

I tried to change the address in `UseSubscriptionService` to `http` instead of `msmq`, but it doesn't work. If I set **computer's A** MSMQ service to Hardened Mode, the client application running on **computer B** get's a timeout while trying to subscribe to `mt_subscriptions`.

```
Bus.Initialize(sbc =>
            {
                sbc.UseMsmq();
                sbc.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
                sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();
                sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/test_queue_client");
                sbc.UseSubscriptionService("msmq://m3-dev1/mt_subscriptions"); // maybe I could use http instead of msmq, but it doesn't work
            });
```

Any clues on that??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, MassTransit does not support HTTP for MSMQ. You could, in theory, add your own transport that supports that. RabbitMQ is a way better transport than MSMQ in every way except if you need to enroll in distributed transactions. And RabbitMQ only requires a single port open between the boxes.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was thinking. But I was also wondering if there's a reason why MassTransit doesn't support MSMQ transport over HTTP. As far as I know, it's quite easy to send messages to a remote queue via HTTP using MSMQ (simply by changing it's address string), however you can't receive messages from a remote queue via HTTP. However MassTransit uses local queues in every host to receive messages, so wouldn't be there a way to implementing it without much pain in MassTransit? And unfortunately I can't use RabbitMQ...

Comment: Yeah, I understand not being able to use RMQ. I'm sorry :(. So you could implement sending via HTTP but it's not really the way MT works.  Like I said, you could implement/re-implmement MSMQ transport to use HTTP for sends. It's just not something we've ever needed to support and isn't as robust.

Answer (score 3):

Our approach for distributed integration is to have a custom web service contract with proper security. This defines an **input port**. The input port actually publishes messages to mass transit buses.

On the other side, the same contract is used to deliver messages to subscribers.

By having a custom contract and http/https transport we are independent on actual message bus in the middle. And this pays of, we were using another bus for like 2 years and 2 years ago we migrated to mass transit based bus without ANY changes to clients (publishers/subscribers).

Comment: Seems like the way to go. I also want the application to be independent with regards to the message bus, in a way that it has to be easily changed if needed.

Comment: Actually, this approach gives you a lot of freedom in implementing input and output ports with security measures you have a total control of. For example, we have implemented message level security for our web service port. Messages are signed and only signed messages are accepted. Since the singing is performed at the inport/outport boundary, the actual flow inside the bus doesn't even have to involve security - the bus is not available from outside.

Comment: This is how we do integration with other systems as well. I think it's a good approach. Also, the input service literally does nothing but sends a message to a queue so the service is always responsive.