# Masstransit queue producer/consumer between node.js and c#

Tags: c#, node.js, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

I am using micro services architecture with Rabbitmq and Masstransit on multiple C# .net core services.
There is a shared dll (nuget) which holds all the interfaces which represents the queue messages.

For example -

Message interface which is stored in a private nuget (dll) and shared between two micro services.

```
namespace MyServiceBus.MessageContract.Commands.Doc
{
    public interface IProcessDoc
    {
        string JobProcessingId { get; set; }
        string RetailerCode { get; set; }
        string UserName { get; set; }
        string UserId { get; set; }
        string StringifiedDoc { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So that we can use it like so -

One micro service publishes:

```
...
_servicePublishEndpoint.Publish<IProcessDoc>
```

other micro services consume the message:

```
public class ProcessDocConsumer : IConsumer<IProcessDoc>
{
       .
       .
       .

       public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IProcessDoc> context)
        {
            var requestData = context.Message;
            // do something.
}
```

This is working well but there are two problems.

1. I am having to share a dll on a "micro service" environment
2. I want to implement consumers on node.js micro services as well.

---

Is it possible to continue using Mass Transient and somehow disabling the need to have this shared interface (with its signature namespace etc..)?
So I will be able to implement the consumer / producer models on each service separately (node.js included) while also still being able to use Mass Transient as the C# solution.

EDIT:

I managed to solve the first Nuget(DLL) issue.
I created the same model on both of the services and made sure to keep the same naming (namespace + class name) and it is working well.

Comment: I would not repost the same answer, take [a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572644/does-masstransit-support-msmq-over-http-transport). In short - think of a more high-level contract based on WSDL/REST so that you hide masstransit internals behind a higher level layer. In case of node.js consumer this would mean you have an actual C# consumer that consumes messages and just **forwards** them to the node.js using WSDL/REST web services.

Comment: @WiktorZychla sorry for the late response.
I am considering to create a c# service to be used as the consumer for my node.js apps.
But before I do that, it seems kinda odd to me that there is no way to consume a message from the queue just because the producer was from a c# mass transient source? 
Shouldn't it be possible to tweak the consumer details a bit so that he will be able to take that message from the queue? or maybe I am missing something about the behind the scene implementation of queue communication?

Comment: @lvgi: this would be possible if you 1) change the default mass transit message serializer to a serializer you can handle at the node.js side or 2) implement the deserializer matching the mass transit serializer in node.js. Since both sound cumbersome, we decided to wrap the internal queue communication with high level WSDL based adapters. But you are free to go, drop a note if you succeed.

Comment: @WiktorZychla It does sound complex. About your suggestion, if I understand correctly.
A valid option can also be to create a small minimal c# service which consumes the messages and sends them via rest-http to the appropriate node.js service rest api?
(maybe later on we can consider how to make a full separation of the messaging logic regardless of who publish and who consumes)

Comment: A c# broker between two apps would miss mass transit features: 1) pub/sub based on explicit subscription definition (a single publisher sends to multiple receivers) 2) a queueing infrastructure in the middle that acts like a throttle, depending on the number of MT agents (so that if too many messages arrive, each message waits in a rabbit queues until an agent is free to handle it).

Comment: @WiktorZychla I see, I am not so familiar with high level WSDL based adapters and how to use it to wrap the messages communication. Can you please direct me to a good source for reading about it? : )

Comment: I also need to somehow use it or maybe a different approach to integrate it with my .net core web api based micro services some of which currently have publishers or consumers as needed. If I am not mistaken the option you talk about  is a technology which is used for "older" types of services? web-services soap and xml configurations? I am not sure if those things can be integrated all together in some way for today usage?

Comment: @lvgi: WSDL is just an example, REST would be fine. The important element here is to expose well defined HTTP-based contracts and hide your messaging infrastructure. The communication goes then like this: publisher pushes a message to a REST endpoint, the REST endpoint uses MassTransit internally to push the message to the Rabbit, a MassTransit agent picks the message and pushes it to a REST endpoint of the subscriber.

Comment: This way what your modules see is the WSDL or REST contract but internally you still have MT with pub/sub and rmq. BTW. Some time ago I migrated to Rebus, it's like MT but has an easier [topic based subscription model](https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2019/02/topic-based-pubsub-data-bus-with-rebusfm.html). The same with MT is [more complicated](https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2019/03/topic-based-pubsub-data-bus-with.html).

Comment: Thanks for all the details mate!, so to see if I understand you correctly, can I still use a new c# service? It will serve as the REST endpoint of the publishers. It will receive the message via http request (from the publishing service) and will actually publish it via its internal hidden MT logic. On the other hand, this new service will also hold a separate logic for the different subscriber services. So for each new subscribing service I will have to implement basic MT consumer logic which consumes the message from the queue and sends it to the REST endpoint of the subscribing service?

Comment: @lvgi: yes. My implementation goes a step further and doesn't need a new MT consumer for each subscriber but rather - I have a configuration database, I read the configuration dynamically and create subscribers dynamically, based upon the database contents. This way I can dynamically reconfigure the database and just restart the service without the need to add extra code each time we add a new subscriber.